# Javascript adding new column with primary key of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a simple csv file like below. I want to read that file and find lat and long value from a webservice than write it as new columns in to the arrays objects.
I can read csv, import it, I can get lat and long values. But when i try to update array it does not work. Sometimes it update only one row, sometimes 2 rows (it is meaningless) but i can not update all off the row, what i need.
I am working on a react habitat. My webservice and code is below. I will be happy if you help me to find my bug. Thanks.

orderid,postcode,weight
1,BB9 7BP,5000
2,E4 9JB,3500
3,WR1 2RX,10000
4,WR5 2AD,5000

```
function getCoordinatesForAddresses(event) {
    orders.map((e) => {
      let url = `https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=${e.postcode}&polygon_geojson=1&format=jsonv2`;
      axios.get(url).then((res) => {
        orders.find((ord) => ord.orderid === e.orderid)["latitude"] =
          res.data[0].lat;
        orders.find((ord) => ord.orderid === e.orderid)["longitude"] =
          res.data[0].lon;
      });
    });
  }
```

when i want to see all array i can see i have added new colums
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa8Oa.png)
but when i want to see one by one i could not see my new colums but when i expand object i see the values in the object.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAsdL.png)
it is very interesting for me. I tried with filter, find and nearly everything.

Comment: You are missing a closing brace on your find methods.

Comment: I'm wrong, your braces are correct. Only difference I can see between your first image and your second image is the casing of "Longitude" and "Latitude" - try and get the casing consistent and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: Yes i saw the difference but it is also meaningless. When i expand first two lines the same description in the object.

Comment: For me,I couldn't understand that "what exactly your question about?"

Comment: it is a bit easy actually but let me explain a bit more. I have a list off addresses(my current array) and i want to find their lat and long values. I can find them from an api but i can not add them to the my current array so i can not use it for my next operations. I have shared my array and my function code and my api. if you have a environment easily you can add my code and see what i mean. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe API did not respond your result that's why you couldn't update arr.Don't use `Array.map` loop for async task...Also It doesn't make any sense because you didn't return anything  in `Array.map`

Comment: When i log on console i can see the values. And also when i expand the object i can see the values in the object but system can not see. It is interesting. If the system acts for all rows i can solve but it is acting differently for the different rows.

Comment: I have found my mistake. It is all about asynchronous issue. I have to wait first operations finish then i should do next operation. When i exec suddenly data has not come totally and the sysetm show only what they get. I need to add async structure. Thanks for the reply. I am closing my issue.